# How to get wordpress header in my own PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications

In wordpress  I just created a my own PHP file  inside my wordpress theme folder , I need the theme's header & footer in the created page . How to do this . I tried it by placing the get_header() inside the file but it showed me a error that the function is not defined .

Comment: Start with [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: `Generally this happens when someone has mistakenly put index.php from a theme in the WP install folder, where it overwrites the index.php that is the main WordPress file.

Download WordPress again, and take the one file, index.php from its root folder, replacing the file you now have as index.php

It sometimes means someone has loaded an entire theme into the root WP folder, also`